# Rewrite rule - redirect dynamic url to a subdirectory without loop

Tags: loops, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdirectory

I have these possible path to images:

/media/thumbnail/img.jpg
or
/media/thumbnail/product/img.jpg
or
/media/thumbnail/product/some-text/img.jpg

All have to be redirected to:
/media/thumbnail/uploads/img.jpg

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^/media/(.*)/(.*)$ /media/$1/uploads/$2 [L,R]
```

but i get an error loading the page due to a loop so I need to stop if the path contains a folder called uploads.

**EDIT:**
There's another problem, the rule I'm asking for must works with this one:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ uploads/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

Which redirects /img.jpg to /upoloads/img.jpg

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule in your .htaccess doesn't match leading slash.

Change your code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^./]+\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif)$ /uploads%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /(?=[^/]*$)([^.]+\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif))$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^media/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /media/$1/uploads/%1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Now it's better:  

OK /media/thumbnail/img.jpg  --> /media/thumbnail/uploads/img.jpg --------
 
NO /media/thumbnail/some-text/img.jpg  --> /media/thumbnail/uploads/img.jpg

Comment: NO /media/thumbnail/img.jpg --> /media/thumbnail/uploads/img.jpg ------------------------------------------------------------- NO /media/thumbnail/some-text/img.jpg --> /media/thumbnail/uploads/img.jpg  :(

Comment: yes its better to have a separate rule for that new requirement.

Comment: NO /media/thumbnail/img.jpg --> /media/thumbnail/uploads/img.jpg ------------------------------------------------------------- NO /media/thumbnail/some-text/img.jpg --> /media/thumbnail/uploads/img.jpg ;(

Comment: Don't understand your cryptic comment but `/media/thumbnail/img.jpg` and `/media/thumbnail/some-text/img.jpg` both get redirected to `/media/thumbnail/uploads/img.jpg` with above rule (tested on my web server).

Comment: Uhm... very strange. I'm testing this .htaccess on a windows8 machine with xampp installed on a virtualhost with a symfony2 application.
I will try on a clean folder and let you know.

Comment: I setted up the folder structure on my linux hosting (www.devsign.it):
- there's a img.jpg in /media/thumbnail/uploads
- the .htaccess with your rewrite rules is in the root.

www.devsign.it/media/thumbnail/img.jpg works but
www.devsign.it/media/thumbnail/some-text/img.jpg doesn't works